# Nested if-statements without brackets

Tags: java, if-statement, brackets

following code is given:

```
       if (c2-c1==0)
        if ( c1 != c3 )
                    {...}
```

How do I interpret this code? The first if-statement comes without *{}*. Is the code above equal to the following code?:

```
 if (c2-c1==0){
    if ( c1 != c3 )
                {...}
 }
```

Comment: As people have answered, yes, they're equivalent to the compiler. But **don't do that**. For this very reason. "Always use braces" is one of the basic maintainability guidelines for all of the languages whose syntax derives from the B language (C, Java, C++, C#, ...). There may be one or two one-liner exceptions for the lazy, but other than that, Just Do It. With proper tools you basically never have to type them anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  The if statement applies to the next statement after it - which happens to be another if in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are equivalent

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. Putting no brackets means that the only instruction in the first if is the other if, which can contains anything you want.