# Concise syntax for javascript if statements without curly brackets

Tags: php, javascript

So pragmatically, I've got a quick and dirty answer to what I'm looking for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057827/nested-if-statements-without-brackets).  But why isn't using that a good idea?  Why can't I find any formal documentation of it?  Is it not part of the spec and standard?  Is it not widely supported?  Is it just because minification could break code using that syntax?

If you could point me to more comprehensive docs of the feature, I'd appreciate that.  What defines the contents of the `if` block?  Is it indentation based?  If it was, that'd be interesting.

On another note, is there something similar to this syntax for `if` statements in PHP?  I can swear that I've seen them being used here and there, but I can't find any examples off hand.  Am I just crazy and it actually doesn't exist in PHP, or can those types of `if` blocks be used in PHP?  Does such an `if` block support having an `else` as well, both in JS and PHP?

It seems that there's an indentation based one as well as a single-line based syntax as well.  What can you tell me about the following?

`if(condition) do_some_statement();`

Thanks

Comment: White space in JavaScript never has structural semantics like in Python.

Comment: Strongly recommend reading even just a basic guide to both languages.

Comment: T.J. - Would crockford's **The good parts** qualify?

Comment: And any corresponding book you'd recommend for PHP?

Comment: @haxxerz: Unfortunately, Crockford -- who is an intelligent and well-informed person -- has a tendency to express his opinions as facts, which I find off-putting. I also found a disturbing flat-out error in the inheritance section of *The Good Parts* he used to promote his preferred mechanism over the standard one. But I haven't read the book as a whole (just parts of it and the mostly-excellent articles on his website). I like *JavaScript: The Definitive Guide* by Flanagan, and of course [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript) is a great resource.

Comment: @haxxerz: For PHP, http://php.net seems great, I haven't delved into PHP much.

Comment: @haxxerz: Oh, er, um, also [I blog about JavaScript](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/search/label/javascript) on occasion.

Comment: I'll check out yer blog.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14542/discussion-between-haxxerz-and-t-j-crowder)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> But why isn't using that a good idea?

Because it's hard to maintain.

> Why can't I find any formal documentation of it? Is it not part of the spec and standard?

Of course it is, see [§12.5 - The `if` Statement](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.5) and [§12 - Statements](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12) in the spec. The body of an `if` is a *Statement*. One kind of *Statement* is *Block* ([§12.1](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.1)), which allows a list of statements to be treated as one statement, but there are many other kinds of statements.

> Is it not widely supported?

Universally.

> Is it just because minification could break code using that syntax?

A good minifier won't break that syntax. (A good minifier will make *use* of it, in fact.)

> What defines the contents of the if block? Is it indentation based?

The body of an `if` statement consists only of the statement following it, indentation has no significance in JavaScript. So all of these are equivalent:

```
if (foo)
    bar();
charlie();

if (foo) bar();
charlie();

if (foo)
bar(); charlie();

    if (foo)
bar();
    charlie();
```

In the above, **only** the call to `bar` is conditional on `foo`; `charlie` is called regardless.

That's why we have *Block*, the *Statement* that introduces a list of statements to be treated as a unit (a block, you might say :-) ):

```
if (foo) {
    bar();
}
charlie();

if (foo) { bar(); }
charlie();

if (foo) {
bar(); } charlie();

    if (foo)
{ bar(); }
    charlie();
```

Indentation is important for humans, though, so keeping consistent indentation is a good idea. The first example in each of the above is probably clearest (of the ones listed) for us mere mortals. :-)

> On another note, is there something similar to this syntax for `if` statements in PHP?

I'm not a big PHP-head, but it looks identical, defined in [Control Structures - `if`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php). There are examples with and without `{}`. (There's also a different, alternative syntax I won't go into here.)

> Does such an `if` block support having an `else` as well, both in JS and PHP?

Yes, `if` supports `else` both with and without blocks.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome, comprehensive answer!

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11688034/1471104) was also very to the point and well-put.

Comment: Done. [dummy chars to meet length req.]

Comment: I've merged in Pointy's answer, linked two comments up.  TJ- would you mind also covering `condition && statement() || statement()` syntax and the precedence of those operators in your answer?

Comment: @haxxerz: That would be a completely separate question. But really, I'd recommend doing some reading before posting it.

Comment: TJ- could you link an article?  I'm picking up the good parts from a friend come monday.

Answer (score 3):

javascript is not white space sensitive, meaning

```
if(condition) do_some_statement();
```

is the same as

```
if(condition)
    do_some_statement();
```

that being said, omitting braces in a single line if statement is always frowned upon because it can lead to bugs if the if statement ever needs to be modified:

```
if(condition)
    do_some_statement();
    // someone adds another line here, without adding the braces
    // now you've introduced a bug
```

also, is it really that hard to write `{ }`? :P

Answer (score 0):

The statement following an `if` is just that: a **statement**.

One of the possible forms a statement can take is that of a brace-enclosed **group** of statements.

Thus, the syntax of an `if` statement is

```
if ( expression ) statement
```

Thus the reason that braces improve maintainability is that they provide an **explicit** boundary to the scope of influence of the `if` control flow effect.

Comment: This was very concise and to the point but i don't have upvoting priveleges yet.

Comment: @haxxerz you should be able to upvote now; congrats! The answer merge you suggested was declined, though. T.J. didn't say this; Pointy did.

Answer (score 0):

> why isn't using that a good idea?

It is far to easy to add another statement and expect it to only fire if the `if` passes

> Why can't I find any formal documentation of it?

The [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else):

*Statement that is executed if condition evaluates to true. Can be any statement, including further nested if statements. To execute multiple statements, use a block statement ({ ... }) to group those statements.*

[ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) (page 89):

*if ( Expression ) Statement*

> It seems that there's an indentation based one

No. Just an if, then a condition, then a statement. The statement can be formatted on the same line or the next line.

White space is not significant in JS.

Answer (score 0):

It is standard, part of the spec ([if-statement](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.5), [other statements](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12)) and supported everywhere. Minification does not break it, because whitespaces have no semantics in JS - it even will enforce it for one-line-statements to save the two braces.

So, it is widely used (without problems!) as well. Sometimes it is considered bad because appending statements to the indented body without adding the braces can lead to problems. Also, it can lead to erratic behaviour when used in nested ifs:

```
if (false)
    if (whatever)
         ;
else
    alert("");
```

Would you have expected an alert? No, the `else` belongs to the last `if`.

Yet, you can use it unconcerned for one-line-statements that are sure not to get extended, like `return;`.